# python different import behaviour on osx and ubuntu

Tags: python, macos, ubuntu, import

I have the same python project on 2 computers running osx and ubuntu 14.04

I am running a script in the `phd_thesis.non_linear_features_selection` folder 
At the beginning of the script I import some functions as:

```
import numpy as np
#from phd_thesis.non_linear_features_selection.example_datasets.polynomial_datasets import *   # it works only on OSX                                                                                             
from example_datasets.polynomial_datasets import * # it works only on ubuntu
```

I have to use a different import path on osx and ubuntu. Why is this happening? How can I have a single import that works on both os?

EDIT: The project is a bit messy. Here the tree structure:

```
onbeo@donbeo-OptiPlex-790:~/Dropbox/pythoncode/phd_thesis/non_linear_features_selection$ tree
.
|-- checkpoint
|-- deep_learning
|   |-- autoencoder_fsca.py
|   |-- autoencoder_fsca.py~
|   |-- autoencoder_j2m.py
|   |-- autoencoder_j2m.py~
|   |-- autoencoder_magic.ckpt
|   |-- autoencoder_NC60.ckpt
|   |-- autoencoder_parkinson.ckpt
|   |-- checkpoint
|   |-- mnist_autoencoder.ckpt
|   |-- nn_j2m.py
|   |-- nn_j2m.py~
|   |-- nn_selector_magic_nino.py
|   |-- nn_selector_magic_nino.py~
|   `-- results
|-- elm_fsca_j2m.py
|-- elm_fsca_j2m.py~
|-- elm_fsca_poly_example.py
|-- elm_fsca_poly_example.py~
|-- elm_fsca_various_datasets.py
|-- elm_fsca_various_datasets.py~
|-- example_datasets
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- polynomial_datasets.py
|   |-- polynomial_datasets.py~
|   `-- __pycache__
|       |-- __init__.cpython-34.pyc
|       `-- polynomial_datasets.cpython-34.pyc
|-- examples_issc2016.py
|-- examples_issc2016.py~
|-- __init__.py
|-- j2m_results_plot.py
|-- j2m_results_plot.py~
|-- neural_network_lasso.py
|-- neural_network_lasso.py~
|-- non_linear_regression_examples_plot.py
|-- non_linear_regression_examples_plot.py~
|-- non_linear_regression_examples.py
|-- non_linear_regression_examples.py~
|-- non_linear_regression_simulated_data_tables.py
|-- non_linear_regression_simulated_data_tables.py~
|-- parity_function_example.py
|-- parity_function_example.py~
|-- polynomial_data_example.py
|-- polynomial_data_example.py~
|-- __pycache__
|   `-- __init__.cpython-34.pyc
|-- real_data_example.py
`-- results
```

The script that I am running is `|-- polynomial_data_example.py` (6th element from the bottom)

Comment: how is the structure of your project?  my opinion and not the answer for your question: u shouldn't use  `import *`

Comment: do you have the file __init__.py in `examle_datasets` and `polynomial_datasets`?

Comment: I have included part of the project tree

Comment: The second import for ubuntu is the right import. It shoulds work for OSX, windows and linux too. But, you can try it. in the __init__.py  under example_datasets: `from .polynomial_datasets import *`. And in your script: `from example_datasets import *`. If itn't work, can you please post the error message!

Comment: Check if any of the files have not sync'ed correctly on OSX. Dropbox may have an error message/conflict for something so it hasn't created a local version on OSX or the local version is incorrect/corrupt.

Comment: I added the line to the `__init_` file and its working.  Dropbox was actually complaining. I do not know if the error was due to dropbox or the `__init__` file. Anyway it is working fine. Thanks a lot :)